# How to set a wildcard subdomain to be used as the CNAME value in client's DNS provider

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, cname

I'm building a system for a bookshop.

Let's say my base domain is **books.thelibrary.com**

And I also have ***.books.thelibrary.com**. The purpose of this wildcard domain is to have the editorial names as the last top level domain and only serve the books from that editorial. For instance: **pearson.books.thelibrary.com** or **santillana.books.thelibrary.com**.

Then the editorial should be able to use this domain as their CNAME value. So let's say Pearson has **pearson.com** as their base domain. Then I would want them to set a new CNAME with `books` as name and the value pointing to `pearson.books.thelibrary.com`. So that Pearson readers are able to use **books.pearson.com** and be served with my app.

The subdomain **pearson.books.thelibrary.com** is working correctly. But if my client (Pearson) uses this in its CNAME record it won't work.

How can I debug this config?

How can I make this to work for my client's CNAME?

<sub>Disclaimer: I'm not actually building a bookshop system and Pearson is not my client, but for the sake of the example is great</sub>

Comment: You need to configure this in your webserver/application settings (it is fairly simple, but exact steps depend on which webserver are you using).

Comment: Your question is offtopic here. But do debug DNS problems: 1) use online tools like DNSviz 2) use local tools like `dig` but always specify the nameserver you query, with `@`, starting with checking the authoritative nameservers and then only recursive ones.